# Need Assistance Filling a Textbox with a Value Determined by a Dropdown List on Razor Page

Tags: asp.net, textbox, dropdown, razor-pages

I have reviewed similar questions and answers here, but just don't seem to be connecting all the dots.

Currently, I have a CreateModel that has the code below. However, I would like for the SWIS to be automatically populated when someone selects the MuniName from the dropdown since these are both stored in the same Municipality table.

```
<td style="width: 30%">
     <div class="mb-3">
          <label asp-for="Official.MuniName"></label>
          <select asp-for="Official.MuniName" id="Select1" class="form-select" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.DisplayMuniName.OrderBy(x => x.Name),"Name", "Name"))"><option value="" selected disabled>---Select Municipality---</option></select>
     </div>
</td>
<td style="width: 10%">
     <div class="mb-3">
          <label asp-for="Official.SWIS"></label>
          <input asp-for="Official.SWIS" class="form-control" />
          <span asp-validation-for="Official.SWIS" class="text-danger"></span>
     </div>
</td>
```

Here is my .cs for the CreateModel:

```
using Referrals.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Referrals.Model;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Referrals.Pages.Officials;

[BindProperties]

public class CreateModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
    public Official Official { get; set; }
    public CreateModel(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Municipality> DisplayMuniName { get; set; }


    public async Task OnGet()
    {
        await _db.Official.Select(a => a.MuniName).ToListAsync();
        DisplayMuniName = await _db.Municipality.ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _db.Official.Add(Official);
            await _db.Official.AddAsync(Official);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            TempData["success"] = "Official added successfully.";
            return RedirectToPage("Index");
        }
        return Page();
    }
}
```

I'm just not sure where to put the code for "If MuniName is this, then SWIS is that." I'm assuming it would be via a foreach?

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

A common pattern for this requirement is to write JavaScript code that hooks into the `onchange` event of the dropdown, and calls into [a named handler](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/handler-methods#named-handler-methods) that takes the selected value as a parameter and returns the matching value, and then updates the input with it.

The JavaScript code goes into the *Create.cshtml* file, something like this that uses the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to make the request:

```
@section scripts{
    const dropdown = document.getElementById('Official_MuniName');
    const input = document.getElementById('Official_SWIS');
    dropdown.addEventListener('change', () => {
        fetch(`/officials/create?handler=swis&muni=${dropdown.value}`)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(swis => input.value = swis);
    });
}
```

The handler method is added to the *Create.cshtml.cs* file:

```
public async Task<ContentResult> OnGetSwis(string muni)
{
    // return the SWIS value based on the muni parameter
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks so much for your reply. When adding this code to my Create.cshtml view, and the Create.cshtml.cs, I receive the following error on the .cs: CS1998 This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU bound work on a background thread.

Comment: Also, I am not sure how to format the control for the SWIS field:                 <div class="mb-3">
                    <label asp-for="Official.SWIS"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Official.SWIS" class="form-control" />
                </div>

Comment: If your `OnGetSwis` method calls into a database, you should prefix the call with `await`, like in your `OnGet` and `OnPost` methods. If it doesn't call into a database, make the signature `public ContentResult` instead of `public async Task<ContentResult>`

Comment: Take a look a the code you wrote in your `OnGet` and `OnPost` methods.

Comment: Are you saying I need something like this, but for the SWIS value? -         await _db.Official.Select(a => a.MuniName).ToListAsync();
        DisplayMuniName = await _db.Municipality.ToListAsync();

Comment: You only need one value so you would use `FirstOrDefaultAsync()` instead of `ToListAsync()`.

Comment: I think you don't need to add a `public IEnumerable<Municipality> DisplaySWIS { get; set; }`,you only need to return it in `OnGetSwis`.

Comment: How does my view need to change to "accept" the SWIS value? Right now, I have:                 <div class="mb-3">
                    <label asp-for="Official.SWIS"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Official.SWIS" class="form-control" />
                </div>

Comment: I also have another @section Scripts, so am getting an error that I already have one defined. If I try to combine them, it doesn't work.

Comment: public async Task<ContentResult> OnGetSWIS(string muni)
    {
        await _db.Official.Select(a => a.SWIS).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    } //Returns an error of: CS0161. 'CreateModel.OnGetSWIS(string)',: not all code paths return a value. Also on hover over the 'muni' portion of that epxression says: IDE0060: Remove unused parameter 'muni' if it is not part of a shipped pubic API.