# How to Use Javascript for Razor Page to Reference a field in Table Based on A Dropdown Selection

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, syntax, razor-pages

I have an app that I am working on. It has a Client Table, an Attendance Table and a Panel Table.

Panels are selected to assign Attendance to Clients. On my Create Attendance page, I have a dropdown with the names of Panels. Following that dropdown are fields to have the cost of the panel, the amount the client has paid towards the panel and the amount left outstanding.

The Panel table contains the panel date, name of the panel and the cost of the panel(Panel Fee in the Panel Model).

What I would like to have done on the Create Attendance page is that once I select the correct Panel Name from the dropdown and tab out of that dropdown, that the Panel Cost field then populates based on the panel selected. (grabs the Panel Cost from the Panel table for that selected panel).

After the cost is filled into this read-only field, I would then enter the Amount Paid and the page would calculate the Amount Outstanding.

I don't know Javascript and have received help with what I have so far, along with researching what might work to finish it out.

I don't know the Javascript syntax to properly reference the Panel Name and Panel Cost fields to make this happen.

Here is what I have so far:

Attendance Create.cshtml:

```
@page
@model SampleApp.Pages.Attendances.CreateModel

<form method="post">
    <div class="border p-3 mt-4">
        <div class="row pb-2">
            <h2 class="text-primary pl-3">Add Client to Panel</h2>
            <hr />
        </div>
        <div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>
        <table class="table table-borderless" style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 25%">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label asp-for="Attendance.ClientId"></label>
                        <select asp-for="Attendance.ClientId" id="Select1" class="form-select" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.DisplayClientData.OrderBy(x => x.ClientDisplayName),"Id", "ClientDisplayName"))"><option value="" selected disabled>---Select Client Id---</option></select>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 80%">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label asp-for="Attendance.PanelAssigned"></label>
                        <select asp-for="Attendance.PanelAssigned" id="PanelName" class="form-select" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.DisplayPanelData.OrderBy(x => x.PanelName),"PanelName", "PanelName"))" onchange="assignData()"><option value="" selected disabled>---Select Panel---</option></select>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table class="table table-borderless" style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 25%">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label asp-for="Attendance.PanelCost"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Attendance.PanelCost" id="PanelCost" class="form-control" readonly />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Attendance.PanelCost" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 25%">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label asp-for="Attendance.AmountPaid"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Attendance.AmountPaid" type="number" id="AmountPaid" class="form-control" style="text-align:right" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Attendance.AmountPaid" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 25%">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label asp-for="Attendance.AmountOutstanding"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Attendance.AmountOutstanding" type="number" id="AmountOutstanding" class="form-control-plaintext" style="text-align:right" readonly />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Attendance.AmountOutstanding" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 25%">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label asp-for="Attendance.Status"></label>
                        <select asp-for="Attendance.Status" id="Select3" class="form-select" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.DisplayStatusData.OrderBy(x => x.StatusDesc),"StatusDesc", "StatusDesc"))"><option value="" selected disabled>---Status---</option></select>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" asp-route-id="@ViewData["clientid2"]" style="width:300px;">Add Panel -> Return to Client</button>
            <a asp-page="/Client/Edit" class="btn btn-secondary" style="width: 300px;">Return to Client</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

@section Scripts
{

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function assignData() {
            var contentType = $("#PanelName").val();
            if (contentType == $("#PanelName").val() {
                $("#PanelCost").val("#PanelName").val(PanelCost);
            }

        }
    </script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">

        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            
            function updatePanelBalance() {
                var panelCost = parseFloat($('#PanelCost').val()) || 0;
                var amountPaid = parseFloat($('#AmountPaid').val()) || 0;
                var amountOutstanding = panelCost - amountPaid;
                $('#AmountOutstanding').val(amountOutstanding);
            }

            $('#PanelCost, #AmountPaid').on('input', updatePanelBalance);
        });
    </script>

    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    }

}
```

On the Attendances Create.cs, I have:

```
namespace SampleApp.Pages.Attendances;

[BindProperties]

public class CreateModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

    public Attendance Attendance { get; set; } = new Attendance();
    public Client Client { get; set; }
    public Panel Panel { get; set; }
    public CreateModel(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Panel> DisplayPanelData { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Client> DisplayClientData { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Status> DisplayStatusData { get; set; }

    public async Task OnGet(int clientid)
    {
        Attendance.ClientId = clientid;

        await _db.Panel.Select(a => a.PanelName).ToListAsync();
        DisplayPanelData = await _db.Panel.ToListAsync();
        await _db.Client.Select(a => a.Id).ToListAsync();
        DisplayClientData = await _db.Client.ToListAsync();
        await _db.Status.Select(a => a.StatusDesc).ToListAsync();
        DisplayStatusData = await _db.Status.ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _db.Attendance.Add(Attendance);
            await _db.Attendance.AddAsync(Attendance);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            TempData["success"] = "Client Panel Attendance added successfully.";
            ViewData["clientid2"] = Attendance.ClientId;
            return RedirectToPage("/Clients/Edit", new { id = ViewData["clientid2"] });
        }
        return Page();
    }
}
```

Panel.cs

```
namespace SampleApp.Model
{
    public class Panel
    {
        [Key]
        [Required]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Panel Name")]
        public string? PanelName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Panel Date")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime? PanelDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name ="Fee")]
        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        [Column(TypeName = "decimal(6,2)")]
        public decimal? PanelFee { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Any assistance would be much appreciated. Thanks!!

EDITED TO ADD:
Current Javascript is:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
    const panelCost = {
        @foreach (var p in Model.DisplayPanelData) {
            <text>"@p.PanelName": "@p.PanelFee".ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),</text>
        }
    };

    function assignData() {
        const cost = panelCost[$("#PanelName").val()];    
        $("#PanelCost").val(cost).trigger('input');
    }
    
    function updatePanelBalance() {
        const panelCost = parseFloat($('#PanelCost').val()) || 0;
        const amountPaid = parseFloat($('#AmountPaid').val()) || 0;
        $('#AmountOutstanding').val(panelCost - amountPaid);
    }
    
    $('#PanelCost, #AmountPaid').on('input', updatePanelBalance);
        }
    </script>
```

This is not working. What am I missing? Once I tab out of the Panel Assigned dropdown, the Panel Cost does not populate. I can enter the Amount Paid, but the Oustanding Amount stay blank. I think that is because I never get the Panel Cost inserted, so nothing calculates. Do I need to change the updatePanelBalance to something else instead of 'input'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know the Javascript syntax to properly reference the Panel Name and Panel Cost fields to make this happen.

You already have that wired up correctly using the `onchange` attribute:

```html
<select asp-for="Attendance.PanelAssigned"
        id="PanelName"
        class="form-select"
        asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.DisplayPanelData.OrderBy(x => x.PanelName),"PanelName", "PanelName"))"
        onchange="assignData()">
    <option value="" selected disabled>---Select Panel---</option>
</select>
```

You could of course also use JQuery’s `on()` method, like you do further down. Some folks, including MDN, will tell you never to use the event attributes (ignore them, “inline event handler” attribs are cool and dope).

In `assignData()` you have a syntax error. A `)` is missing from the `if` statement. Also the `if` statement will always be true because its condition is fulfilled literally one line earlier.

I don’t understand this next bit, but I feel like you’re generally on the right track:

```js
$("#PanelCost").val("#PanelName").val(PanelCost);
```

You can set the value of the PanelCost input field like so:

```js
$("#PanelCost").val(3.50).trigger('input');
```

The question is, where do you get the correct value from?

Also note you need to manually trigger the input event when setting the field’s value programmatically (you don’t *need* to, but the rest of your specific code depends on it).

Here is the full thing, using the value of the selected `PanelName` as `PanelCost`. Note I changed all the `var`s to `const`, because they don’t need to be changed. I also got rid of `$(document).ready` but feel free to put it back. There was also an errant `}` at the beginning of the second script tag (syntax error).

```js
function assignData() {
    const contentType = $("#PanelName").val(); //?
    $("#PanelCost").val(contentType).trigger('input');
}

function updatePanelBalance() {
    const panelCost = parseFloat($('#PanelCost').val()) || 0;
    const amountPaid = parseFloat($('#AmountPaid').val()) || 0;
    $('#AmountOutstanding').val(panelCost - amountPaid);
}

$('#PanelCost, #AmountPaid').on('input', updatePanelBalance);
```

In general it’s a good idea to check your browser console when testing javascript, as it will point out the syntax errors. Your IDE can likely also be set up to catch syntax errors.

---

The above assumes your PanelCost comes directly from the `<select>`’s value.

Let’s say you can’t do that for some reason. Another way might be to put it into a `data-` attribute:

```html
<option value="" selected disabled>---Select Panel---</option>
<option value="1" data-cost="3.50">First Panel</option>
<option value="2" data-cost="9.99">Second Panel</option>
<option value="3" data-cost="5000">Panel III</option>
```

Then you would get it like so (above, change your handler attribute to `onchange="assignData(this)"`):

```js
function assignData(select) {
    const option = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
    const cost = option.dataset.cost;
    
    $("#PanelCost").val(cost).trigger('input');
}
```

---

Maybe you can’t do that either. You might store them in a javascript dictionary and look them up by the selected value. I would advise you to use the Panels’ Ids for this, but currently you’re using their names, so it would look like this. This will break if a PanelName contains a `"`.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  const panelCost = {
    @foreach (var p in Model.DisplayPanelData) {
      <text>'@p.PanelName': '@p.PanelFee?.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)',</text>
    }
  };

  function assignData() {
    const cost = panelCost[$("#PanelName").val()];
    $("#PanelCost").val(cost).trigger('input');
  }

  function updatePanelBalance() {
    const panelCost = parseFloat($('#PanelCost').val()) || 0;
    const amountPaid = parseFloat($('#AmountPaid').val()) || 0;
    $('#AmountOutstanding').val(panelCost - amountPaid);
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#PanelCost, #AmountPaid').on('input', updatePanelBalance);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: The question is, where do you get the correct value from? The Panel Cost value comes from the Panel Model (PanelFee). When the user selects the panel to assign in the Attendance.PanelAssigned dropdown (also a value from the Panel Model (PanelName), I want the PanelFee to be automatically filled in the Attendance.PanelCost field. Just not sure how to do that part. I can do the fixed value as you show, but PanelFees vary based on selected panel. Can you assist? Your code above does not error out, but does not pass the PanelFee into the Attendance.PanelCost field. Thank you!!

Comment: I have added all that I have for my Create.cshtml.cs.

Comment: @MelB Could you just put the `PanelCost` into the `option`s’ `value` attributes? Otherwise maybe store it as a `data-` attribute: `<option value="1" data-cost="9.99">First Panel</option>`. Would that work for you?

Comment: @MelB i added some options to my answer

Comment: I considered this option. The thing is that Panels are always being added and I won't know the cost of the panels ahead of time. That's why the panels are added to the Panel table with that info - so the user can add them rather than a developer hard coding them. I actually asked this question before for another app, but could not understand the replies I received and it was never resolved. You can view that question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74321916/need-assistance-filling-a-textbox-with-a-value-determined-by-a-dropdown-list-on Maybe this will give you an idea?

Comment: Hm, what’s stopping you from doing this: `asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.DisplayPanelData.OrderBy(x => x.PanelName),"PanelFee", "PanelName"))"`? I.e. using `PanelFee` as the select value, while keeping `PanelName` as the displayed value for the dropdown. That way you could always use the selected value for further calculations with users none the wiser.

Comment: Hmmm. Good thought. However, I need to run reports against these values. That might mess them up.

Comment: So do the thing with the lookup table (javascript dictionary/object)? You can just foreach `Model.DisplayPanelData` and output the ID and the fee. Then upon selection you look up the fee from the dictionary.

Comment: Do you have a sample you could link to that shows this? I am not sure how to execute this code-wise. What do I place where? I've been trying to do an .include statement in my OnGet hoping that would work, but nothing yet.

Comment: yeah i added the razor stuff to my last example. as you can see, it’s disgusting. just do this instead, it will be fine, unless you need to post back the *name* of the selected panel for some reason: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77989522/how-to-use-javascript-for-razor-page-to-reference-a-field-in-table-based-on-a-dr/77990767#comment137504836_77990767

Comment: HI. I made edits, but my Panel Cost and Amount Oustanding fields are not populating. I have added current javascript to my post above. Do you see anything?

Comment: Okay, I added the whole entire Javascript to my answer. You had syntax errors preventing the whole thing from running. Also, you should define the functions outside of `$(document).ready()`, because you need them to be visible outside of that function. **Check your browser console, it will tell you what you’re doing wrong.** You also had the quotes around the PanelFees wrong, but you’re right that you need them. I didn’t have them at first, because they’re just decimals, but since they’re nullable, I added the quotes back and used the null-coalescing operator `?.`.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works now. I was getting an error w/o the quotes. I knew I needed them, but wasn't sure where to place them! Thanks for pointing out where I was going wrong! Much appreciated.